# Loading html inside PHP for heroku

Tags: php, html, heroku

I have created separate HTML and jquery sites for iPhone and Ipad. Cause I have used Heroku for deployment I have to have a PHP index. So I have included Html inside PHP. It loads the index.html inside there's folders.but the links are broken( CSS, Images ).
Is there any solution of alternative for that?

```
<?php
    
    echo $width = "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";
    echo $height = "<script>document.write(screen.height);</script>";
    
    
    if($width!=null && height !=null) {
        if($width>376 && $height>812){
            include_once("ipad/index.html");
        } else {
            include_once("iphone/index.html");
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('outcome'=>'error','error'=>"Couldn't redirect. Redirecting to iPhone version"));
    }
    
?>
```

[image: file structure]

Note -
I have tried something like this

```
<?php

echo $width = "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";
// echo $height = "<script>document.write(screen.height);</script>";

if($width!=null) {
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    if($width>376){
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path .= "/StanstedGo/ipad/index.html";
        include_once($path);
    } else {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path .= "/StanstedGo/iphone/index.html";
        include_once($path);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('outcome'=>'error','error'=>"Couldn't redirect. Redirecting to iPhone version"));
}

?>
```

but it also does not solve my problem. I still have broken links to CSS files.